# Hide port and address with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

I've installed a sonarqube and a Jenkins server in one machine, with ports 9000 and 8080 respectively. I'd like to make urls like test_hub.mysite.com/sonar and /jenkins and redirect to machine and port correctly, but maintaining original address test_hub.mysite.com/sonar.

My configuration with nginx is pretty simple:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sonar.mysite.com;
    location /sonar/ {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://52.29.xx.xx:9000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test_hub.mysite.com;
    location / {
          # you can use regular exp also
        if ($request_uri = /sonar) {
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
          proxy_pass         http://52.29.xx.xx:9000;
        }
        if ($request_uri = /jenkins) {
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
          proxy_pass         http://52.29.xx.xx:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: Check this [link](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) before trying